# ObserveSingleEvent does not work good

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My realtime database looks like this:

[image]

It contains only 1 child as you can see. I had 4 more children in RunningGames a few minutes before. I deleted them in the browser. When now calling this:

```
private lazy var runningGamesRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("RunningGames")
 self.runningGamesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            for gameSnap in snapshot.children {
                let id = (gameSnap as! FIRDataSnapshot).key
                print(id)
}
})
```

It still prints those games I deleted in the browser. Calling `runningGameRef!.removeValues()` in my app does deletes it in the browser and on the iPhone (the print(id) is fixed). I have this error on multiple observeSingleEvent functions on different children, not only children of RunningGames. What would cause this annoying error?

Some children in RunningGames also have children, but they do auto remove themselves in the app. However, these values are also still visible when calling observeSingleEvent.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it's probably getting the outdated info from the device's local cache.

Comment: Is persistenceEnabled set to yes?

Comment: Yes, would that cause the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably your local cache that's still holding the outdated info. This often happens when you're manipulating data from multiple sources.

I would try using `observe` instead of `observeSingleEvent`. I know it's a bit odd (and not really what you want if you only want to load the data once) but that should keep your info up to date.

Maybe by doing this you could fetch the info just once.

```
var handle: UInt = 0
  handle = ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    for gameSnap in snapshot.children {
      let id = (gameSnap as! FIRDataSnapshot).key
      print(id)
    }
  ref.removeObserver(withHandle: handle)
})
```

[Source of the code (Frank van Puffelen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539699/remove-observer-after-value-change-in-firebase)

Comment: Is there really no way to load data just once? I just want to check some values in some rooms... It is strange it does not work properly, it should not save that in the local cache. I just want to check the values at that moment for one time only.

Comment: Edited my answer, you could try that.

Comment: "argument labels do not match with any available overloads" I think it is because I want to loop through the value gotten from the snapshot in observeSingleEvent. Can observe give me a snapshot?

Comment: I might just have the syntax wrong, I didn't test it. Where is it giving that error? On the removeObserverWithHandle or on the loop?

Comment: Yeah, I was using the outdated syntax, it should work now.

Comment: I called the keepSynced(true), it now works as well. Thank you